# How can I add a newline (in each row of a text file) exactly three characters after a certain character(comma in this case)?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file with country, city and state info, among other information. The content of the file looks something like this:
(only the part pertaining to the question shown)

```
Some lines (rows) of text
...
United States
Memphis, TN 38116-3252
...
More lines of text
...
United States
Austin, TX 78726
...
```

What I would like to do is add a newline before the zip code or after TN (for example) and also replace the ',' with a newline. But I'm assuming the second part will be easier.

Desired format:

```
Some lines (rows) of text
...
United States
Memphis
TN
38116-3252
...
More lines of text
...
United States
Austin
TX
78726
...
```

The end goal is to import the data into a spreadsheet like:

```
Some info | Country | State | City | Etc.
abc       | United..| Texas | Austi| zcx
```

I'm open for anything that works sed, awk, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `sed` for this:

```
sed -E 's/, /\n/;s/([A-Z]{2}) /\1\n/' States  
Some lines (rows) of text
...
United States
Memphis
TN
38116-3252
...
More lines of text
...
United States
Austin
TX
78726
```

The first expression `s/, /\n/` searches for a comma followed by a space and replaces with newline.

The second expression `s/([A-Z]{2}) /\1\n/` searches for any two uppercase letters followed by a space, and replaces with those letters followed by a newline.

---

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

Comment: This is better but still not perfect. Why do you need two expressions as you're already using a backref... ?

Comment: I don't, but at least for me, this makes it easier to read!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to work. Actually I'll see if I can make use of only the last part of the expression first and then look for other options to replace the comma because I just noticed that there's a few commas that shouldn't be replaced with newlines.

Comment: Now, do you see why a single expression is better ? `'s/, ([[:upper:]]{2}) /\n\1\n/'` ensures that only the comma+space that precede the name of state will be replaced by a newline.

Comment: @don_crissti Haha! I didn't say otherwise. I appreciate your feedback a lot, and thanks again for correcting my initial error due to sloppy reading!

Comment: @don_crissti  LOL. I like your comments buddy. ;)

Comment: So why don't you put @don_crissti 's comment somewhere in your answer so that I can accept it?